# Trying to make anonymous function, inside an anonymous function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, math, anonymous-function, nested

Hi there this might me a very noob question but I'm stuck, and I'm trying to do this for a while, please help me.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
a=0.5;
ODE= @(x,y) ((-2*(a^2)*x*y)/(x^2+y^2)^2)/(1-((a^2)*(x^2-y^2)/(x^2+y^2)^2));


%The classical RK4 solution as a function
k1 = ODE(x,y);
k2 = ODE(x+0.5*dx,y+k1*0.5*dx);
k3 = ODE(x+0.5*dx,y+k2*0.5*dx);
k4 = ODE(x+dx,y+k3*dx);
rk4= @(x,y,dx) y + 1/6*(k1 + 2*(k2+k3) + k4)*dx;
```

So I first define ODE as an anonymous function then I'm trying to define k's from the ODE and finally RK4 from k's.

But this doesn't work. Any suggestion what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `k1` through `k4` are not being defined or used as functions. When you declare `k1 = ODE(x,y)`, this tries to evaluate the `ODE` function with vectors `x` and `y` that aren't defined. What you probably mean to say is :

```
k1 = @(x,y,dx) (ODE(x,y));
k2 = @(x,y,dx) (ODE(x+0.5*dx,y+k1(x,y,dx)*0.5*dx));
k3 = @(x,y,dx) (ODE(x+0.5*dx,y+k2(x,y,dx)*0.5*dx));
k4 = @(x,y,dx) (ODE(x+dx,y+k3(x,y,dx)*dx));
rk4= @(x,y,dx) (y + 1/6*(k1(x,y,dx) + \
                2*(k2(x,y,dx)+k3(x,y,dx)) + \
                k4(x,y,dx))*dx);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.  
And I have a question. If I wanted to define a separate function file calculating rk4, what should I do?  
I mean I cannot use @(..) in function files. What's the replacement?

Comment: You can still define anonymous functions in the body of a regular function, so if your function file starts with `function rk4=RK4(ODE,x,y,dx)`, then the body can just be the code above, with the `@(x,y,dx)` removed from the rk4 line.